# How can I create a JSON file from an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm currently searching for a way to create a JSON file (versions.json) with a key and a value from an object within JavaScript. To create the JSON file, I've this object here:

```
["V1_config-interfaces.json","V2_config-interfaces.json","V3_config-interfaces.json","versions.json"]
```

I need to loop now some way over this object and check if the current file is not the `versions.json` because this is the created file.

The JSON file must looks like this:

```
{
    "V1": "V1_config-interfaces.json",
    "V2": "V2_config-interfaces.json",
    "V3": "V3_config-interfaces.json"
}
```

So the key is always the version number before the underscore. What I've tried is this here:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const interfaces = fs.readdirSync('./src/interfaces/');

fs.writeFile('./src/interfaces/versions.json', JSON.stringify(interfaces), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('versions.js successfully created');
});
```

But this generates the same result like the object looks like. So how can I reach my goals?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? JSON notation of an array may look exactly like js notation,e.g  `JSON.stringify( [1,2,3])` yields `"[1,2,3]"`

Comment: @EriksKlotins Dude... read my whole question. I've wrote how the JSON file must looks like "The JSON file must looks like this:" and this is not the case.

Comment: "I've this object here"...that's not an object, it's an _array_. So first you need to write some code to transform your structure. You'll need to extract the property names ("V1" etc) from the first two characters of the values in the array. You'll also need to exclude the last item in the array from your final object, by the looks of it. So...what have you researched? What have you tried? We're happy to _help_ you with your problem, but this is not a free write-my-code service. Most people here expect some attempt from you yourself before we spend our time voluntarily to assist you . Thanks.

Comment: Assign an empty POJO to a var/let, for each element in the original array use a string function to get chars before the first underscore. You can then nameOfPOJO["extractedID"]=originalArray[i]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Array#reduce and regex. This strips the file version and adds it as a key to your object and ignores anything that doesn't have a version number. It also checks if the version has `_` character following immediately after.

```js
const data = ["V1_config-interfaces.json","V2_config-interfaces.json","V3_config-interfaces.json","versions.json", "V4shouldntwork.json", "shouldntwork_V5_.json", "V123_shouldwork.json"];

const res = data.reduce((a,v)=>{
  const version = v.match(/^V[1-9]+(?=_)/);
  if(version === null) return a;
  a[version.shift()] = v;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Mr.Jo updated the answer to take into account version numbers larger than 9. So V10 etc will work.